# Node Post Date equals to selected date only not time?

Tags: 7, views

I created a view and exposed a `Post Date` filter. I select a date and I want to show the post of that date. But it searching based on "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS". I just want to show full day data. I set the operator `is equal to`.

Comment: I think `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` is wrong. That option is not accessible. It's only date by default. Not time. But if I'm wrong and if you really found daytime in the contextual filters please explain where. Since I'm looking for it over an hour now. And there's only date. Not time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Install the [date](https://drupal.org/project/date) module and enable the "Date Views" module, which is a sub-module of the date module.
2. To your view add the filter "Date: Date (node)".
3. For the "Date selection form element" option set it to whatever you like.
4. For the "Filter granularity" option set it to "Day".
5. Set the "Starting year" option to whatever is relevant.
6. For the "Date field(s)" option select "Content: Post date"
7. For the "Method" option, generally leave it set to "OR"
8. Click the apply button, then continue to configure as you would normally.